# Событие активации анимации

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть код который активирует анимацию при двойном клике по `form1`, а нужно чтобы анимация срабатывала при двойном клике по компоненту `webBrowser1` и по срабатыванию `button1`. Как поменять?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer tmr;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDoubleClick += Form1_MouseDoubleClick;
        this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
        tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 10;
        tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
    }

    int x;
    int step = 5; 
    void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        x = 0;
        tmr.Start();
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        x += step;
        if (x > this.Width)
        {
            x = 0;
            (sender as Timer).Stop();
        }
        this.Invalidate();  
    }
    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, x, 4);
    }

}
```

Comment: `button1` - это кнопка WinForms или кнопка в html-разметке?

Comment: Кнопка winforms

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += StartAnimation;
            this.DoubleClick += StartAnimation;
            this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
            this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://google.com");
        }

        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.AttachEventHandler("ondblclick", this.StartAnimation);
        }

        private void StartAnimation(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //код анимации
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как вставлять код анимации? Не понятно.

Comment: Код метода Form1_MouseDoubleClick вставьте в StartAnimation

Comment: Как не пробую не получается. Вы можете добавить в ответ?